# Using Sync Framework on databases with different schemas

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to use MS Sync Framework to synchronize different tables (with completely different structures) in different databases, assuming one of the tables has a primary key and the other a unique index whose values coincide with the first table's PK (but cannot be promoted to PK)? The column names can be different too.

Answer (score 4):

that should be possible, have a look at these series of posts:

[Part 1 – Upload Synchronization where the Client and Server Primary Keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/upload-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

[Part 2 – Bidirectional Synchronization where the Client and Server Primary Keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/part-2-bidirectional-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

[Part 3 – Synchronizing tables where Client and Server Primary Keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/part-3-synchronizing-tables-where-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

Comment: Thanks!!!! I don't quite understand all your code yet (I'm new to the MS Sync Framework), but I get the main idea of mapping the keys and "tricking" the SF. Other than Microsoft, can you recommend some sites/blogs for in-depth SF knowledge? I'm going to need it.